# Loop to import arguments into R

Tags: r, bash, loops

I am new to R and I am trying to have a script get arguments from a file. I am using the following code within my R script:

`args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
covr <- args[1]
rpts <- args[2]`

The arguments will come from a parameters.tsv which will have two fields, one for each argument.

I want to run the R script with the parameters given in a line from parameters.tsv until all lines have been used to run the R script.

The end result will be qsub'ing a bash script to run each line into the R script.

This is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat parameters.tsv | while read v1 v2; do RScript --slave ‘--args $v1 $v2’ myscript.R; done
```

It's currently terminating almost immediately after i submit it and i don't understand why.
Any help is greatly appreciated since i am very new to this and anything i read prior did not explain in enough detail to grasp.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want to do but would suggest looking at the commands source() and readLines() to start with

Comment: I want to run a R script, within the script are two variables. I wish to run the script n timea with different values for the two variables. These variables will come from a tsv file that has n number of lines with a value for each variable. I want to loop those variables in to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
var_df <- read.csv([your_file_here]) # or read table with correct specs

for (i in 1:dim(var_df)[1]) { # vectorise for speed; doing it with loops to 
# make this clearer
   this_var_a <- var_df[i,1]
   this_var_b <- var_df[i,2]

   source([Rscript file here], local=TRUE) #set local=T as otherwise the vars
# will not be visible to the script's operations

}
```